# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n\log(n!)}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

Im trying to determine whether or not the following series converges:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n\log(n!)}$$

Any hints/tips on how to approach?

Thanks.

Comment: Stirling's formula?

Comment: @lulu I am not familiar with it.

Comment: $\log(n!)\sim n\log(n)$ and $\int_2^\infty\frac1{x^2\log(x)}\,\mathrm dx<\infty$.

Comment: [Stirling's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)

Comment: @lulu I am not allowed to use that formula. Is this the only way to show convergence?

Comment: I don't understand.  That page contains proofs of the formula, as well as for weaker versions (which I'm sure would be strong enough to get the job done).  Use one of those.

Comment: @firev2 you can just use $\log(n!)=\sum_{k=1}^n\log(k)\sim n\log(n)$

Comment: Note that $n! \ge 3^n$ for $n$ big enough, hence $\frac{1}{n\ln(n!)} \le \frac{1}{n\ln(3^n)} = \frac{1}{n^2 \ln(3)}$

Comment: @lulu Come on, maybe OP is doing a first course in calculus. Stirling's formula is way beyond that, and you don't need anything as advanced for this simple exercise.

Comment: Another approach: it is easy to show that $n! > (\frac{n}{2})^{n/2}$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since $n!=1\cdot 2 \cdot 3... \cdot n \geq 2^{n-1}$, we can use the comparison test with

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\log(2^{n-1})}=\frac{1}{\log2}\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(n-1)}$$

the latter of which clearly converges, since $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges.

Comment: +1 for a method that requires very little knowledge. If I may suggest one small improvement in that direction, $\sum_n\left(\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac1n\right)$ telescopes, so its convergence is _more_ obvious than that of $\sum_n\frac{1}{n^2}$.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a very elementary solution. We don't need all the strength of the Stirling's Approximation.

Observe that $$e^n = 1+n+\frac{n^2}{2!}+\cdots+\frac{n^n}{n!}+\cdots > \frac{n^n}{n!}$$

so $n! > (\frac{n}{e})^n$. It follows $\log(n!)> n (\log(n)-1)$.

Then $$\frac{1}{n\log(n!)}< \frac{1}{n^2 (\log(n)-1)}$$ for $n>2$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes, I got this. Thanks.